# The update function doesn't work, SQL Server and ASP.NET MVC 5

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, stored-procedures

I have to update a table but it doesn't do anything. In the view for edit my values, it "works", but when I click to submit changes, it doesn't change any values in the data base. I'm really stuck, I check this files but I can't see where the problem is.

This is my .cs file

```
 public void update(Propietario objPropietario)
 {
        try
        {
            comando = new SqlCommand("spEditarPropietario", objConexion.getConexion());
            comando.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

            comando.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", objPropietario.IdPropietario);
            comando.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Nombre", objPropietario.Nombre);
            comando.Parameters.AddWithValue("@IdTipoDocumento", objPropietario.TipoDocumento);
            comando.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ValorDocumento", objPropietario.ValorDocumentoId);

            objConexion.getConexion().Open();
            comando.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            throw;
        }
        finally
        {
            objConexion.getConexion().Close();
            objConexion.cerrarConexion();
        }
}
```

The table:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Propietario]
(
    [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [IdTipoDocumento] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Nombre] [varchar](100) NOT NULL,
    [ValorDocumento] [varchar](30) NULL,

    CONSTRAINT [PK_Propietario] 
        PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([ID] ASC)
                    WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, 
                          IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, 
                          ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, OPTIMIZE_FOR_SEQUENTIAL_KEY = OFF) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Propietario] WITH CHECK 
    ADD CONSTRAINT [FK_Propietario_TipoDocumentoId] 
        FOREIGN KEY([IdTipoDocumento]) REFERENCES [dbo].[TipoDocumentoId] ([ID])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Propietario] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_Propietario_TipoDocumentoId]
GO
```

This is the stored procedure that I'm using:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE spEditarPropietario  
    (@id int,
     @Nombre VARCHAR(100),
     @IdTipoDocumento int,
     @ValorDocumento VARCHAR(30))      
AS
BEGIN
    UPDATE [dbo].Propietario
    SET Nombre = @Nombre, 
        IdTipoDocumento = @IdTipoDocumento, 
        ValorDocumento = @ValorDocumento
    WHERE ID = @id      
END
```

This is my controller:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Update(int ID)
{
    Propietario objpropietario = new Propietario(ID);
    objetoPropietario.find(objpropietario);
    return View(objpropietario);
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Update(Propietario objpropietario)
{
    objetoPropietario.update(objpropietario);
    return RedirectToAction("Inicio");
}
```

I have this find method and it works well.

```
public bool find(Propietario objpropietario)
{
        bool hayRegistros;

        try
        {
            comando = new SqlCommand("spVerPropietario", 
objConexion.getConexion());
            comando.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

            comando.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", 
objpropietario.IdPropietario);

            objConexion.getConexion().Open();

            SqlDataReader read = comando.ExecuteReader();
            hayRegistros = read.Read();

            if (hayRegistros)
            {
                objpropietario.IdPropietario = 
Convert.ToInt32(read[0].ToString());
                objpropietario.Nombre = read[1].ToString();
                objpropietario.TipoDocumento = 
Convert.ToInt32(read[2].ToString());
                objpropietario.ValorDocumentoId = read[3].ToString();
                objpropietario.EstadoError = 99;
            } 
            else
            {
                objpropietario.EstadoError = 1;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            throw;
        }
        finally
        {
            objConexion.getConexion().Close();
            objConexion.cerrarConexion();
        }
        return hayRegistros;
}
```

This is the stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE spVerPropietario     
    (@ID int)      
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT ID, Nombre, IdTipoDocumento, ValorDocumento 
    FROM [dbo].Propietario 
    WHERE ID = @ID     
END
```

Comment: Couple quick things before we look further - are you sure the `@id` value that you are passing to the stored procedure has matching row in the table? Also, can you turn on SQL profiler and see what query is being received by the DB.

Comment: Can you show us the **connection string** that you're using in your C# code for connecting to this SQL Server?

Comment: Does it throw an error? If not, have you put a breakpoint in the update method to make sure that it is being called?

Comment: Thimmarasu Lanka, thank you for that answer, I didn`t know about SQL profiler, when I use it the @id was 0, so that is the issue. I checked the files but I don't see the problem yet. I have a find function and it works properly.

Comment: It doesn't throw any error.

Comment: Please show your find method.

Comment: Jonathan Willcock, I added the find method,

Comment: As an aside, please use the other methods of the DataReader, instead of ToString, for example `read.GetInt32(0)`. This is much more efficient than ToString followed by Convert.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed adding a new parameter of the id, to the Update method in controller, because the object changes the id to 0, that's why it didn't work. The solution:

```
public ActionResult Update(Propietario objpropietario, int ID)
    {
        objpropietario.IdPropietario = ID;
        objetoPropietario.update(objpropietario);
        //return Content(obj.propietario.Nombre 
        //return View(objpropietario);
        return RedirectToAction("Inicio");
    }
```

Only with that, it works fine.

Comment: I think I realise what your problem was. You did not have the ID on your WebForm. In passing the object to the view, the assumption is that the same object is returned. It is not. Instead a new object is created with all the details that are held on the form. If the ID is not there, it gets lost. The solution is usually to have a hidden field on the form to hold the ID. That way when the form is posted, the ID is not lost.